# Rails - id no longer default parameter in routes after using scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm in the process of localizing my app. To do so, in the route.rb file I enclosed all the routes I have between `scope(:locale)` as follows:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ar/ do
    get 'errors/not_found'
    ...
end
```

Now when I run my tests, I keep getting the errors similar to the following:

> ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit",
> :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"michael@student.guc.edu.eg",
> :locale=>"LGTmMOQtRRw6r3y4a2qGAA"}, missing required keys: [:id]
> app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb:5:in

**EDIT:**

Before adding the :locale part, when I ran rails routes, I'd get the following:

```
edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
```

After adding it, the url became as follows:

```
edit_password_reset GET    (/:locale)/password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit {:locale=>/en|ar/}
```

All the errors are in places where I use urls as follows: `edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email)`

When I edit this to:

`edit_password_reset_url(id: @user.reset_token, email: @user.email)`

the problem is solved. I'm not sure though that this is the right way to solve the problem. So my question is how can I have :id as the default parameter as it was, while using scope?

Comment: have you checked the o/p of rake routes, what is the url formed.

Comment: Yes, I added this above

Comment: Passing the id explicitly is perfectly valid practice, and probably what you need to do with this setup.

Comment: I thought there might be a way to include the locale by default, leaving what I had before intact